# Limit Collection Size to N-number

Tags: magento-enterprise, category, collection

After several research attempts, I still couldn't manage to limit category page to N-number of products to be shown.

I need to limit a specific category page to let's say 180 products only, with pagination as well.

```
$collection->setPageSize(200);
```

Will display 200 products but will still display remaining products because of pagination.

To clear things up:

Only list 3 pages (example 180 products regardless) of a specific category to be shown on the front end regardless of how many products are there in that category.

Comment: To clarify in another way: If the category would display 10 pages, with pagination, you want to cut off at page 3? So in reality you want a max page to display functionality?

Comment: Well not just max  page but rather max products. Let's say 180 products, 60 products per page, so I'll have 3 pages. Or 180 products, 90 products per page, so I'll have 2 pages.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the following value:

System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Frontend:

"Products per Page on Grid Default Value" or "Products per Page on List Default Value" depending on List Mode is set to Grid only or List only.

Comment: This would just limit the number of products per page but doesn't limit the total numbers of products. In my case, should be 180 only, may it be 3 pages or 3 pages